# Storekit: How to check if the product is purchased or not?

Tags: swift, storekit

I think everyone knows that Apple In-App Purchases are a little bit difficult thing to implement. (Especially for Swift newbies).

Anyway, I tried to learn working with it. Maybe it's better to say that I followed the tutorial Kilo Loco made on YouTube. 
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3hJ0rY1NNw&t=3456s)

I did everything what he did and it's working but it's obvious that I don't understand everything yet.

My question is.. how to check if the customer already purchased it or not?

Maybe there's some kind of status?

Then I would just write something like that:

```
if(status=="purchased")
{
   // I would do something what premium user can do.
}
```

I know it's not really clear but I guess who have more experience in it can help me to understand more. (or maybe I should go watch tutorial once again and once again)

THANK YOUU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5456-in-app-purchase-tutorial-getting-started), the section about **Purchased Items**.
In short, you should save locally if the Item has been already purchased, maybe in *UserDefaults*
A more secure alternative is to validate the receipt of the purchase, as shown in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html).

Comment: How can I get the receipt? Store it locally after the purchase?

Comment: How would that work for subscriptions?  For example they could cancel and then it wouldn't renew - if relying on userdefaults the app would think they've still subscribed.  It would be so much better if Apple in app payments worked the same as Android.